# Custom Date and Time Format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, format

I have successfully used the setNumberFormat() function for a range that contained numbers. Is there a similar function for custom date and time formats?

```
// formatting
  eSheet.getRange(earRng).setNumberFormat('_(\"$\"* #,##0.00_);_(\"$\"* \\(#,##0.00\\);_(\"$\"* \"-\"??_);_(@_)');
  eSheet.getRange(datesRange).setNumberFormat('Aug-1930');
```

Hopefully seeing the code will give you a good idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Appreciate any help I can get with this!

Sample input (column A):

[image: earnings before format]

Expected output (column A):

[image: earnings after format]

I can achieve this by going to "Format" -> "Number" -> "Custom date and time", but would like to know how to do the same via code if possible.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I have successfully used the setNumberFormat() function for a range that contained numbers. Is there a similar function for custom date and time formats?` and `Hopefully seeing the code will give you a good idea of what I am trying to achieve.` and your showing script, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output you expect as the image or the values?

Comment: @Tanaike I have just updated the question with the examples you requested, hopefully this will clarify things.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that your question has already been resolved. I'm glad about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Range.setNumberFormat()` with date objects as well, like this:

```
  eSheet.getRange(datesRange).setNumberFormat('MMM-yyyy');
```

See [Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats).